# Transaction doesn't works, saves users with the same email

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, spring-transactions

I have to save users with unique emails. I added Transactional on my saveUser method. But when I tested I saw that I can add users with the same email. Here is my code:

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
    public User saveUser(String email) {
        if (userRepository.findByEmailIgnoreCase(email) != null) {
            throw new UserAlreadyExistException(format("User with email %s already exists.", email.toLowerCase()));
        }

        var user = new User();
        user.setEmail(email.toLowerCase());

        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

UserRepository it is a JpaRepository:

```
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {
User findByEmailIgnoreCase(String email);
}
```

Here is my test (SprinBootTest):

```
@Test
public void shouldNotCreateNewUserWithSameEmail() throws Exception {
    String requestPayload = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(UserCreateRequest.builder()
                                                                    .email(EMAIL1)
                                                                    .rolesName(Set.of(role.getName())).build());
    for (int i=0; i<15; i++) {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(MAIN_REQUEST_URL)
                                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                .content(requestPayload))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").exists())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name.firstName").doesNotExist())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name.lastName").doesNotExist())
                .andReturn();


        var r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(MAIN_REQUEST_URL)
                                            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                            .content(requestPayload))
                            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isBadRequest());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        new Thread(r).start();

        userRepository.deleteAll();
    }
}
```

As you can see I run second user creation in other thread. Test passed when I do 3-5 iterations. But with 10-15 iteration it fails with error:

> Exception in thread "Thread-10" java.lang.AssertionError: Status
> expected:<400> but was:<201>

I.e. user was created. Also I tried to add synchronized to saveUser method, it doesn't helps. What is wrong? And how I can properly prevent not unique emails?

UPD: In User class:

```
@Column(unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private String email;
```

Comment: Why don't you use unique constraint on email in database?

Comment: Indeed, your design is wrong. You should not be using isolation level `SERIALIZABLE` and performing an explicit check. You should have a unique constraint preventing duplicate emails in the database through **any** means, not just through this single method.

Comment: I found a mistake in the test. UserRepository delete method is not Transactional. Need to use service method deleteAllUsers with @Transactional. I deleted deleteAll calling and use a new email (i + EMAIL1) in each iteration. And it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to use hibernate dependency.

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email")})
public class user {

String email;
String displayName;

}
```

Comment: This will only work if you let JPA generate your tables. This is rarely the case except for toy projects, so you should create the unique constraint with the same mechanism as you do for the rest of the DB schema.